# Django: jwt: How can I keep user logged in even the token can expire in one week period

Tags: django, jwt

I am having a mobile app which will show some articles not very sensitive data. My backed is Django with jwt.

I am planning to keep 1 month as token expiration time.

After the token get expired how to refresh the token without the user to login again. I want to keep them logged in for ever as long as one wants, but at the same time i want the token to be changed, becasue some one can misuse it.

How to do this with jwt and Django